# Why is the Tkinter Scroll Bar only active when you hover over it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using Tkinter to create a GUI and the scroll bar is only active when I put my mouse over it and scroll. Is there a way so I can scroll using my scroll wheel on the mouse when the mouse is not on the scroll bar and in the middle of the window?

```
import Tkinter as Tk
from Tkinter import StringVar

class Example(Tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):

        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.canvas = Tk.Canvas(root, width=200, heigh=200,  borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.canvas,background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = Tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((10,10), window=self.frame, anchor="nw", 
                                  tags="self.frame")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)

        self.populate()

    def populate(self):


#####Last Name######
        labelText=StringVar()
        labelDir=Tk.Label(self.frame, text='hello').grid(row=1, column=1)
        labelDir


        labelText=StringVar()
        labelDir1=Tk.Label(self.frame, text='hello').grid(row=2, column=2)
        labelDir1

        labelText=StringVar()
        labelDir2=Tk.Label(self.frame, text='hello').grid(row=1, column=1)
        labelDir2


        directory=StringVar(None)
        self.can_lname =Tk.Entry(self.frame, text=directory,width=100).grid(row=4, column=4)
        self.can_lname

    def OnFrameConfigure(self, event):
        '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think this is related to your problem, but… why are you building the frame's widgets on root instead of on the frame itself?

Comment: Also, what OS and version, Python version, and Tk version do you have?

Comment: Finally, if you're looking to handle mouse-wheel events on the Canvas by sending fake scroll-clicky events to the scrollbar, you do that by calling `self.canvas.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.OnMouseWheel)`. Within that function. Within that function, the `event.delta` will tell you how far the mousewheel moved. There are some tricky bits, and I can't write a whole tutorial here; try searching for "custom mouse wheel Tkinter" or something like that.