# scrolling configuration of tkinter box

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Scrollbar,\
                     Frame, Canvas
import pandas as pd

def testTable(df):

    def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    def mouse_wheel(event):
        global mouseCount
        if event.num == 5 or event.delta == -120:
            mouseCount -= 1
        if event.num == 4 or event.delta == 120:
            mouseCount += 1
        label['text'] = mouseCount

    mouseCount = 0    
    rows= df.shape[0]
    cols = df.shape[1]

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("100x300")

    canvas = Canvas(root)
    frame = Frame(canvas)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
    canvas.create_window((rows,cols), window=frame, anchor="nw")

    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))
    frame.bind("<MouseWheel>", mouse_wheel)


    for i in range(rows):       
        for j in range(cols):
            if i != 0:
                Label(frame, text=df.loc[i,df.columns[j]], width=5, borderwidth="1", 
                 relief="solid").grid(row=i+1, column=j)
            else:
                 Label(frame, text=df.columns[j], width=5, borderwidth="1", 
                  relief="solid").grid(row=i, column=j)
    root.focus_force()
    root.mainloop()

testTable(pd.DataFrame({'colA': range(20), 'colB': range(20)}))
```

1. Is there a way to 'freeze' the first line of the table so that column names don't disappear when scrolling down?
2. How can I change the scroll-sensitive area to the entire table rather just the bar? At the moment, the bar will respond to scrolling only if this is done with the mouse being over the bar area.

The second question is relative to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672739/why-is-the-tkinter-scroll-bar-only-active-when-you-hover-over-it) one but the latter has not received an answer.

Comment: The only way to "freeze" a row is to have it not be part of the scrollable area. So put that rouw outside the canvas. I made this once, [here's how I did it](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/49fa18828cddca44a2befae84cfd67ad).

Comment: Your second question did get and answer: you have to bind to the mousewheel. Exactly how that's done depends on the OS. I made a cross OS compatible version once, [here's how I did that](https://gist.github.com/novel-yet-trivial/3eddfce704db3082e38c84664fc1fdf8).